# IndexedDB error in Firefox 36

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to open an `IndexedDB` with my addon (on Firefox, ver 36, beta).

```
var request = window.indexedDB.open("mydb");
```

the request runs the onerror andI get these errors :

> IndexedDB UnknownErr: ActorsParent.cpp:413 "UnknownError" at this
>   line.

the same add-on works for Chrome.
I tried the same thing in a firefox SDK addon I build and it works.

any help would be appreciated..

Comment: I am having the same issue.  It maybe a Firefox 36 bug.  See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1143003

Answer (score 0):

I tried renaming the storage folder in Firefox > Profiles to "storageBackup" and restart Firefox.  After you restart, try launching the indexedDB app again and Firefox will rebuild a new storage folder.  This fixed my indexedDB issue on Firefox 36.  Likely related to this: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1110067